# How to fill a widget to the full available Row height

Tags: flutter, dart

The layout looks like this:
[image: Layout]

Here is a `Row`, which is inside `ListView`. Inside it's a `Column` with `Text` widgets, leading and trailing widgets. The problem is that the leading widget has to fill the free height of the `Row`. The `Row` height is determined by the `Column` with the `Text` widgets, and the leading widget should adjust to this size and not try to increase the `Row` height to infinity (for example, the leading widget can be a colored `Container` with infinite height and given width). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Thierry's answer is good. But if your row has dynamic height (for example your subtitles have undefined length and row should expand height that depends on it) then you can use `Stack` widget as root widget of your list item to handle this. Here is working code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final leadingWidgetWidth = 120.0;

    return Stack(children: [
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          // This child will fill full height, replace it with your leading widget
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: leadingWidgetWidth,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(width: leadingWidgetWidth),
          Expanded(
            // Here your column with texts
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('Title'),
                Text('Some dynamic text'),
                Text('Some dynamic text'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            // Here your trailing widget
            child: Container(color: Colors.blueGrey),
          )
        ],
      )
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, `Stack` is more elegant than `IntrinsicHeight`, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. `IntrinsicHeight` is an option too, but it can cause performance issues. Especially if you use it inside ListView. From flutter.dev: `This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible.`

Answer (score 26):

[image]

Use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to fill the `height` of a `Row` (`width` of a `Column`), i.e. to stretch along the CrossAxis.

Use `Expanded` widgets to fill the space along the MainAxis The flex attributes will determine the proportion of each widget.

For the trailing widget, just use a `Center` widget to center it.

In order to have your `Row` inside a `ListView`, stretching to the height of the tallest child, put the `Row` inside an `IntrinsicHeight` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Row and Column',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: MyWidget()),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        MyTextWidget(
                          text:
                              'I like to believe that science is becoming mainstream.',
                        ),
                        MyTextWidget(
                          text:
                              'There is no known objects accounting for most of the effective gravity in the universe.',
                        ),
                        MyTextWidget(
                          text: "Let's explore because it's fun.",
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                      child: SizedBox(height: 40.0, child: MyWidget()),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const MyTextWidget({Key key, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        child: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(color: Colors.blueGrey),
    );
  }
}
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Row and Column',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: MyWidget()),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        MyTextWidget(
                          text:
                              'I like to believe that science is becoming mainstream.',
                        ),
                        MyTextWidget(
                          text:
                              'There is no known objects accounting for most of the effective gravity in the universe.',
                        ),
                        MyTextWidget(
                          text: "Let's explore because it's fun.",
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                      child: SizedBox(height: 40.0, child: MyWidget()),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const MyTextWidget({Key key, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        child: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(color: Colors.blueGrey),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my `Row` is inside a `ListView`. In my case, the `Row` height is stretched due to the `Text` widgets inside, it doesn't have a fixed height. In your case, the `Row` is limited to the dimensions of the `SizedBox`.

Comment: I see. This is what IntrinsicHeight is for. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you want them to have a maximum size of the main-axis you can add an attribute
`mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` if you want it to be minimum size, then use `MainAxisSize.min` instead (works on Row and Column)

if you want to make a cross-axis on max size, then you can add SizedBox before them and then add height or width with double.infinity
like this `height: double.infinity`

Comment: I forgot to mention that my `Row` is inside a `ListView`. In my case, the `Row` height is stretched due to the `Text` widgets inside, it doesn't have a fixed height.

Comment: then you can add SizedBox and add size to it. using `MediaQuery.of(context).size` is recommended if you want to make it responsive

Comment: by the way, if i saw your cases, the Row height is flexible which follow it's children's size in total
then if you want to stretch the left most item, then you can just add double.infinity, BUT you have to define the maximum size of the Row (you ned SizedBox before them)